# Entity Framework: Getting exception while inserting row in MySQL Table

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I recently switched my database from SQL Server to MySQL. I am still using Entity Framework 6 to do CRUD operation in database. When I was using SQL Server as backend then I was setting "StoreGeneratedPattern" as "Identity" to Primary Column of Table so that it could generate unique GUID. I am following the same approach in MySQL but I am receiving below error. The only difference is that data type of Primary Key in SQL Server was GUID and it is varchar in MySQL with UUID() as default. Can you please help in identifying the issue?

Whenever I set "StoreGeneratedPattern" to None and give Primary Key an arbitary value from code then it is working fine. However I dont want to generate Primary Key value from code.

> Object Reference not set to an instance.

**MySQL Table**

```
CREATE TABLE Gender
(
    org_genderid VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT(uuid()),  
    org_gendername varchar(100) NOT NULL,   
    org_ispublished bit NOT NULL,       
    org_createdby varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    org_createdon datetime NOT NULL,
    org_modifiedby varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    org_modifiedon datetime NOT NULL
);
```

**Entity Framework to insert the data**

Please note that every property used here contain value

```
using (var ctxAddGender = new STREAM_EMPLOYEEDBEntities())
            {
                var entGender = new gender()
                {
                    org_gendername = vmGender.Name,
                    org_ispublished = true,
                    org_createdby = vmGender.CreatedBy,
                    org_createdon = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime(),
                    org_modifiedby = vmGender.ModifiedBy,
                    org_modifiedon = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime(),

                };

                ctxAddGender.genders.Add(entGender);

                int success = ctxAddGender.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Identity as StoreGeneratedPattern**

[image]

**Stack Trace**

```
   at MySql.Data.EntityFramework.ListFragment.WriteSql(StringBuilder sql)
   at MySql.Data.EntityFramework.SelectStatement.WriteSql(StringBuilder sql)
   at MySql.Data.EntityFramework.InsertStatement.WriteSql(StringBuilder sql)
   at MySql.Data.EntityFramework.SqlFragment.ToString()
   at MySql.Data.EntityFramework.InsertGenerator.GenerateSQL(DbCommandTree tree)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommand(DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.CreateCommand(DbModificationCommandTree commandTree)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.CreateCommand(Dictionary`2 identifierValues)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.<>c.<Update>b__21_0(UpdateTranslator ut)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update[T](T noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStore>b__153_0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass148_0.<SaveChangesInternal>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at Application.Business.BLL.BusinessLayer.GenderBLL.AddGender(GenderViewModel vmGender) in G:\onMyTune\IP\MySQL Projects\Project Acceleration - Employee Web API\Application.Business\BLL\BusinessLayer\GenderBLL.cs:line 33
   at Application.WebAPI.Controllers.GenderController.AddGender(GenderViewModel vmGender) in G:\onMyTune\IP\MySQL Projects\Project Acceleration - Employee Web API\Project Acceleration - Employee Web API\Controllers\GenderController.cs:line 36
```

Comment: Are you sure this error relates to uuid thing ? may be some other part of code is throwing this exception can you add some more details related to this object reference error?

Comment: Hi @MKhalidJunaid, I have added Stack Trace in the post. Hope it is helpful. Please let me know if you require anything else.

Comment: Can you check `GenderBLL.cs:line 33` part what it says may be the main object is null and you are trying to use its property

Comment: My initial guess is that `vmGender` is not properly set or its null

Comment: I checked that vmGender is not null. This is failing even when I am assigning hardcoded values to the column instead of reading from vmGender. It also didnt work when I am setting hardcoded value explicitly to Primary Key column org_genderid as well. Is it like Identity dont work for primary Key column having string data type in MySQL?

Comment: This seems likely to be a MySQL EF bug; for example, see this similar crash that has been reported: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71242. You could report it to Oracle at bugs.mysql.com, but you would need to boil it down to a simple reproducible test case that shows the problem.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. However in my case I am not using unsigned bigint data type for primary key column.

Comment: If I set "StoreGeneratedPattern" to None and generate Primary Key value from code then it is working fine. However this is not I want to do. I have added ny observation in original post as well.

Comment: Do you have Key and DatabaseGenerated.Identity set on field org_genderid?

Comment: Yes. Key as in Primary Key and DatabaseGenerated.Identity set on field org_genderid.

Comment: EF doesn't autogenerate values for string based keys as far as I know. See my answer below regarding generating the key using `Guid` from your C# code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem may be that EF is validating your primary key as being `NULL` before it attempts to perform the update/insert. If this is the case;

In your entity class set the genderid value to `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()`.

Comment: If I set value explicitly like you have mentioned then it will work. I know this. My only concern is that if suppose Guid.NewGuid generates same key twice for same table then exception will occur as the column is primary key. It would be much better if database generates automatically but it seems it will not generate automatically if I keep varchar for primary key.

Comment: I see your concern, but exactly how many guids are you planning to create? There is an very low chance of generating the same guid, even across different machines.

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid?view=net-6.0

Comment: Not sure why allowing your sql server to generate the guid is ok, but letting C# do the same isn't, their uniqueness should be equivelant. I use this as does Microsoft in their code without incident. It is the default for string based Id's.

Answer (score -2):

Try some of the following:

- Reset the AUTO_INCREMENT using ALTER TABLE Gender AUTO_INCREMENT = 0 if table is empty.
- You could just recreate the table.
- Delete the mapped entity from your project then re-import it from the database.

Comment: I fail to see how any of your comments offer any help. There is no `AUTO_INCREMENT` in his table schema.